# New MVC2 Application Suggestion

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm starting a project in ASP.NET MVC2 where I have a need to let the user select item(s) from a table with about 40000 records. This is NOT a shopping cart application.

I'd like to accomplish this using JQuery popup. Here is the order I have in mind...

Please think of this as building a new car

1. Customer starts to build a new car
2. Enters some basic info such as name, # of cylinders etc
3. Clicks an icon to show a JQuery modal popup to search parts required
4. Selects an item/part after the search returns
5. Selected item shows up on the underlying [parent] page.
6. Repeat steps 3, 4, 5 to select additional items/parts.
7. Then Save to database in a Master/Detail type tables

This is similar to a shopping cart except there is no checkout and the user enters the order info before making the selections and I noticed that JQuery interfaces seem to appear richer.

If this is doable, I'm looking for suggestions and/or examples or a path to follow, being new to both MVC and JQuery.

Example of what I want to achieve can be seen at www.pageonce.com, only in a much smaller scale.

TIA
ASP.NET MVC2, MS SQL Server, JQuery

Answer (score 0):

Start with understanding how you will achieve [Ajax with Asp.net MVC](http://www.nikhilk.net/Ajax-MVC.aspx). Another suggestion is that consider moving to Asp.Net MVC 3. You will get Razor view engine and lots of Web Helpers which can enhance your UI further.

Comment: Thanks Pradeep. Only reservation is that MVC3 is still in Beta, but I will look into it.

Comment: Well its road map says it will be out by Jan'11.